# Background video that resizes to always fit the browser

Tags: html, css, video, browser, resize

I'm trying to create a website in which the background is a video. I've been searching for days on how to recreate something like [Spotify's](http://spotify.com/) homepage background but cannot seem to make it work.

My problem is that I can either get the height to scale with the browser, or the width, but not both. Unlike the video on Spotify's website, it doesn't scale to fit the browser at all times. I've tried many things, and most of them I can't remember. I don't mind using JQuery to achieve this effect.

My current code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>VideoBG</title>
<style type="text/css">


#videohome {
    position:absolute; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    top:0;  
    left:0;  
    right:0;  
    bottom:0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


        <video  id="videohome"  preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="" volume="0">
            <source src="./homepage.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at the BigVideo.js plugin for jQuery: http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Comment: I don't see any videos on Spotify’s homepage, only some sort of parallax scrolling.

Comment: @LeBen: this only happens if you visit their website for the first time. He is refering to this particular page: https://www.spotify.com/en/video-splash

Comment: Oh, okay! So they resize the video with JavaScript. You can spend some time expanding their code to understand it or use BigVideo.js as @reinder suggested.

Comment: I tried expanding their source to figure out what they were doing but just couldn't because I'm a bit novice. I've tried for a while and all I could see is that they change their width value on one of their elements dynamically, as the browser changes its width. I'll use the plug in for now, but I really want to learn how I could use javascript/jQuery to resize the video myself. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to have a container div, which fits to the screen, and then add a class to the video which will resize it to width or height.

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
padding:0;
margin:0;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1000;
overflow:hidden;
}

.videoPlayer {
    min-height: 100%;
    //min-width:100%; - if fit to width
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><video class="videoPlayer">Code goes here</video></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `object-fit: cover` in the container

Answer (score 3):

Oldie but a goldie. Have been struggling with this myself but found that aspect-ratio media queries do the job nicely.

If media queries aren't supported, the video will still cover the page but won't scale properly.

If `translateX`, `translateY` or `@supports` isn't supported, the video won't be centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="cover">

    <video autoplay loop mute poster="path/to/image.jpg">
        <source src="path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="path/to/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="path/to/video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="" />
    </video>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cover {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cover img, .cover video {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    left: auto;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

@supports (transform: translateX(-50%)) {

    .cover img, .cover video {
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }

}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){/* Make this the same aspect ratio as your video */

    .cover img, .cover video {
        max-width: 100vw;
        min-width: 100vw;
        width: 100vw;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){/* Make this the same aspect ratio as your video */

    .cover img, .cover video {
        height: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://wesbos.com/css-object-fit/

Use object-fit: cover; on your video tag

It worked for me.

Comment: It should be noted that as of the time of this writing Edge still doesn't fully support object-fit. It only supports using it on <img> tags.
https://caniuse.com/#search=objectfit

Comment: As per the above comment object-fit works in all browsers for video, except for IE and Edge. You can up-vote it on the Microsoft Developer forum here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-elem?category_id=86947  Use a JS polyfill in the meantime, but if it gets more votes it will be implemented.